# How to synchronize returning function values in jQuery?

Tags: json, spring, jquery

I have written this function in jQuery:

```
function checkAvailability(value) {
    var result = true;
    $.getJSON("registration/availability", { username: value }, function(availability) {            
        if (!availability)
            result = false; 
            alert("in getJSON: " + result);
    });
    alert(result);
    return result;
}
```

I have got alert from 'getJSON' after this second. Why has it happened this way?

I have Spring MVC project and Controller method which checks username availability. Controller method works properly. But I receive final result too late. How can I synchronize it to return properly value in my function?

**EDIT**

I am using this function in jQuery validate. I have extracted `checkAvailability()` function during my test.

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkAvailability", function(value, element, param) {    
    var das = checkAvailability(value);
    return das;
}, jQuery.format("Someone already has that username. Please try another one."));
```

And this is my form validate:

```
$(".form").validate({
    rules: {
        username: {
            checkAvailability: true
        },
        ....
    },
    messages: {
    }
});
```

**EDIT 2**

This is my Controller method. It returns boolean value. If username was taken it would return false value.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/registration/availability", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody boolean getAvailability(@RequestParam String username) {       
    List<User> users = getAllUsers();           

    for (User user : users) {
        if (user.getUsername().equals(username)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why does this behave this way?**

[$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is shorthand for making an AJAX request. The 'A' in ajax stands for asynchronous. Meaning, the javascript engine fires the getJSON call and then immediately executes the next lines, which is `alert(result); return result;`

The actual value as returned by the web service will be received by your code at a later point in time. The `success` function that you passed into getJSON will be called once the js engine receives the response from the server. As you can see, it is too late by that point.

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX

**What can I do to make this work?**

That depends on your situation. Who is calling `checkAvailabilty`? If you post some code on how this function is being used, I can give examples with my suggestions.

Off the top of my head, you could either make use of [jquery deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), nice article on [the same](http://addyosmani.com/blog/digging-into-deferreds-1/). Or you could pass in a callback function that is executed from inside your success function.

**EDIT:**

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options

> The serverside resource is called via $.ajax (XMLHttpRequest) and gets
>   a key/value pair, corresponding to the name of the validated element
>   and its value as a GET parameter. The response is evaluated as JSON
>   and must be true for valid elements, and can be any false, undefined
>   or null for invalid elements,

To get a real world idea, check the demo http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/captcha/

Open Firebug or the developer tools of your choice. Go to the tab that lets you see AJAX requests. Enter the captcha, submit. Check ajax request as listed in the developer tool. Notice the query string parameters. Notice the response. Its a simple 'true' or 'false'.

Comment: Thanks a milion for your answer. I have edited my question. I am using it in jQuery validate.

Comment: Updated the answer with a link to the jquery validate documentation. There is an option that is meant to handle your exact scenario.

Comment: It looks very similar. I have just tested this solution. But it seems not working. I am wondering what method in Controller or php function have to return.

Comment: Updated the answer. In future, you would want to edit the question and mention what you just tried and **how** it didnt work. As in the controller code you used, the response the server sent back etc... Without any details, I have answered based on a guestimate of what could have gone wrong :)

Comment: I have posted my Controller method in my question. Thank you for examples. I will check it out.

Comment: Semantically, the check for whether username exists should be done using a GET. Anyway, by default, jquery validate makes a GET request. I am guessing that your server side framework is blocking the request as its not a POST. Firebug is your friend. Only he can help you analyze whats happening and why.

Comment: OK when you were writing it I have resolved my problem. Thanks for your help. I have only written in my `js` file this in validate rules: `remote: "registration/availability" ` without any other options. And change my Controller method `RequestMethod` to the `GET`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps or not but you can use

```
var result;
$.ajax( {
        url : "registration/availability",
        data : data,
        async : false  //syhcrononous ajax request ;)
}).done(function(data) {
    result = data;
});
```

for more info you can refer [JQuery AJAX doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)